# Changing values of multiple input fields based on dropdown option (js or PHP switch)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a dropdown, I need to update three input fields values based on dropdown selection.

Dropdown is like this:

```
 <form action="#" method="post">

  <select id="call_out_fee">
 <option selected disabled>select...</option>
 <option value="fourhundred">400.00</option>
 <option value="threefifty">350.00</option>
 <option value="threehundred">300.00</option>
 <option value="twohundred">200.00</option>
 <option value="zero">0.00</option> 
 </select>

<p>Tech charge: <input name="tech_charge" value="" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.blur()" /></p>
<p>Call out: <input name="call_out" value="" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.blur()" /></p>
<p>Agent fee: <input name="agent_fee" value="" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.blur()" /></p>
```

I can update one of these fields with the following:

```
<script>
function updateTechCharge (el, priceLog, priceList) {
priceLog.value = 'R' + priceList[el.getElementsByTagName('option')     [el.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase()];
}

var techCharges = {
'fourhundred' : 400,
'threefifty' : 350,
'threehundred' : 300,
'twohundred' : 400,
'zero' : 0
};

var select = document.getElementById('call_out_fee'),
hidden = document.getElementsByName('tech_charge')[0];

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
updateTechCharge(select, hidden, techCharges);
});
</script>
```

I tried doing it with PHP switch with no luck.

Since my knowledge of js is very limited and I need to update all three of these fields with different values I am asking for your help.

Values based on dropdown should look like this:

```
option "fourhundred" > 
tech_charge: 400, call_out: 400, agent_fee: 50

option "threefifty" > 
tech_charge: 350, call_out: 350, agent_fee: 60

option "threehundred" > 
tech_charge: 300, call_out: 300, agent_fee: 70

option "twohundred" >
tech_charge: 400, call_out: 200, agent_fee: 80

option "zero" > tech_charge: 400, call_out: 0, agent_fee: 90
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AleksanderRasevic I don't see any place in your example code where you use `JQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way, and would add the class "charge-type" to each input:

```
function updateTechCharge (el, priceList) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('charge-type')

  var price = priceList[el.getElementsByTagName('option')[el.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase()];

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      var item = elems[i];
      item.value = 'R' + price[i];
  }
}

var techCharges = {
  'fourhundred' : [400, 400, 50],
  'threefifty' : [350, 350, 60],
  'threehundred' : [300, 300, 70],
  'twohundred' : [400, 200, 80],
  'zero' : [400, 0, 90]
};

var select = document.getElementById('call_out_fee'),
hidden = document.getElementsByName('tech_charge')[0];

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
  updateTechCharge(select, techCharges);
});
```

[See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjwv7z6x/7/)

Comment: Thank you! That did the job!

Comment: This work perfectly. However, I think my knowledge limitations are worse than I thought :-) ...
Changed values show on screen but are not stored in database after form submit. Field values are "", so there is nothing to store. The js function only displays the amount from within the function and nothing is passed to the database.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check the names of each input to match the one in the server side?

Comment: Yes, tripple checked, I have set them up as INT with length of 3. Query passes all the other fields fine, only those 3 that have been generated by js are not saved.

On the form processing page I have a php mailer script that uses the same $_REQUEST strings from the form and those fields get mailed through, they only dont save to db.

Comment: To rule out the possibility of being javascript the culprit, change one of the values (directly in the input element) to 1, comment the javascript code and submit the form. If the 1 is not saved there is something else wrong. Also, where does the form element end? 
What are you using in the server side? can you update your question with the server code that will save the form?

Comment: I did as you suggested, commented out js and changed value of one of the fields to 1, it save to db just fine. 

Just to mention, I said previously that it doesnt save values, it does save them but with the value of "0".

Comment: try to remove the value attribute from the input elements to see if it fixes the issue

Comment: How are you submitting the form? By the action defined in the form I assume you're using javascript do submit it, right? Can you show that code?

Comment: The form is far too long and confidential to post on here, but here is the action:

<form name="form" method="post" action="process-booking" autocomplete="off" >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178551/discussion-between-elitepc-and-aleksandar-rasevic).

Comment: And on the processing page I convert the form field values to strings and then send them to db, same as everything else:

$call_out = $_REQUEST['call_out'];

$tech_charge = $_REQUEST['tech_charge'];

$agent_fee = $_REQUEST['agent_fee'];

Maybe the problem lies in here? But as I said, manyally entered values save to db just fine.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this little snippet helps you

html:

```
...
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="">nothing selected</option>
  <option value="case1">case 1 text</option>
  <option value="case2">case 2 text</option>
</select>
...
```

js (with JQuery and > ES5)

```
...
let selectNode = $('#select');
selectNode.on('change', (event) => {

  // stop event bubbling and default handling
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagination();

  // get the selected value, if '' set undefined
  let selectedValue = selectNode.val() || undefined;

  // switch by the value with default case
  switch(selectedValue) {
    case 'case1':
      console.log('do something for case 1');
      break;
    case 'case2':
      console.log('do something else');
      break;
    default:
      console.warn('no selection');
  }
}};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it using a case(switch) statement like you asked in your post:

```
 <script>
    //Not necessary
    //var techCharges = {
    //'fourhundred' : 400,
    //'threefifty' : 350,
    //'threehundred' : 300,
    //'twohundred' : 400,
    //'zero' : 0
    //};

//Not necessary
//var select = document.getElementById('call_out_fee'),
//hidden = document.getElementsByName('tech_charge')[0];

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
     //Use case statement on the drop down's value property
     switch(this.value){
         case "fourhundred":
         UpdateTechCharges(400, 400, 50);
         break;
         case "threefifty":
         UpdateTechCharges(350, 350, 60);
         break;
         case "threehundred":
         UpdateTechCharges(300, 300, 70);
         break;
         case "twohundred":
         UpdateTechCharges(400, 200, 80);
         break;
         case "zero":
         UpdateTechCharges(400, 0, 90);
         break;
     }
});

//function to set the input elements
function UpdateTechCharges(techCharge, callout, agentFee){
    document.getElementsByName('tech_charge')[0].value = 'R' + techCharge;
    document.getElementsByName('call_out')[0].value = 'R' + callout;
    document.getElementsByName('agent_fee')[0].value = 'R' + agentFee;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to work, it shows field values "undefined".

Comment: @AleksandarRašević Where does it show field values of "undefined" ?